# Как подключить к Visual Studio 2019 возможность строить UML?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, uml

Не знаю как к проекту wpf на c # добавить возможность строить UML. Подскажите кто знает .

Comment: https://ccse.kennesaw.edu/fye/UML%20VS%20--%20C-Sharp.pdf

Comment: Спасибо большое